# Magento upgrade from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I am relatively new to magento and would like to receive some advice concerning a Magento update from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.3.0. I can't use the intrinsic update feature for several reasons. The main one is, that I develop with a vagrant setup. Changing files in the vagrant box will not be reflected in my IDE. I need to change files directly. I use git to store all my code changes (no changes are in the core). I use a git push deployment strategy for development, staging and production environments.

Possible complications:
- I use several own and 3rd party extensions

So what is the best way to achieve this? Is it enough to copy over all data in app/code/core and then test? Or do I need to consider other things as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would always use the development box for applying updates, and then push the changes via GIT.

If you are limited to only working through your IDE, then there are a lot of changes that you would need to make. Not just in app/code/core, but often updates to app/design, js, lib, skin, etc.

Very rarely does Magento remove files/folders, but it is possible. With a minor patch update, its not going to have too many changes so you could just use a merge function:

```
tar -xvf <filename.tar>
```

or

```
unzip -u <filename.zip>
```

Another option is to manually do it outside of your vagrant system using GIT:

1. Create a new Branch of your project
2. Checkout the Branch on your local system
3. Replace all default Magento directories with the updated 1.9.3.0
4. Verify the changes in a GIT Browser (like SourceTree), being **careful** not to override any customizations
5. Add modifications, Commit and Push
6. Checkout branch on your Vagrant setup, test and verify upgrade worked
7. Deploy to production